# TBB: How to set different number of threads in different parts of code?

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb

I have a `tbb::task_scheduler_init` instance `init` which is initialized with some certain number of threads in a part of code which I don't have control, in later parts of code I want to run with different number of threads. How can I do it through this instance `init`?

Is there a better way than doing the following?

```
init.terminate();
init.initialize(my_preferred_number_of_threads);

/*
 run some code
*/

init.terminate();
init.initialize(original_number_of_threads); // restore the original tbb scheduler
```

Comment: The preferred usage of TBB is to not set the number of threads anywhere, and instead concentrate on getting grainsizes in the right ballpark.  Setting the number of threads (as this example demonstrates) often leads to composability problems.  But if you're stuck with the situation you describe, your approach seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tbb::task_arena for your needs.

Taken from tbb::task_arena documentation

```
tbb::task_scheduler_init def_init; // Use the default number of threads.
tbb::task_arena limited(2);        // No more than 2 threads in this arena.
tbb::task_group tg;

limited.execute([&]{ // Use at most 2 threads for this job.
  tg.run([]{ // run in task group
    tbb::parallel_for(1, N, unscalable_work());
  });
});

// Run another job concurrently with the loop above.
// It can use up to the default number of threads.
tbb::parallel_for(1, M, scalable_work());

// Wait for completion of the task group in the limited arena.
limited.execute([&]{ tg.wait(); });
```